# Pull latest stable release via git

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm currently working with a workflow that makes use of Wordpress as a submodule under git. My workflow involves adding a submodule to my project from the following URL:

```
git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git
```

**The problem:**

Doing this seems to grab the most up-to-date Wordpress version, including the non-stable alpha versions.

I simply want to grab the most recent stable release, and I'm wondering whether there is some specific syntax I can add to the git URL above that allows me to specify a specific branch perhaps?

Thanks

Comment: This is not WP specific and mainly opinion based. For a list of tags use `git tag -l` and to clone a specific tag use `git checkout tags/your-targeted-tag`. Obviously you're always cloning the full repo, but the branch or tag you use is what you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is not possible to *generically* clone/checkout the *latest stable version* with either git or svn.

In either case you have to identify the specific tag (version) you want to pull from with git or svn.  Or, as you've done, just pull trunk (which is the development branch)

For more see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Subversion